# É possível reescrever qualquer código que use ponteiros (C#) sem usar ponteiros em Node.js?

Tags: javascript, c#, c++, node.js, ponteiro

É possível reescrever qualquer código em C/C# que use ponteiros de um modo que faça a mesma coisa sem utilizá-los?

Meu medo são códigos mais complexos. Os simples eu acredito que não haja dificuldades de se reescrever.

Como poderia substituir os ponteiros usando o mesmo conceito em JavaScript?

Comment: @Lucas Duete, eu acredito que a pergunta é pertinente, mas me desculpe mesmo assim. Estou editando a pergunta para ver se melhora e fica mais objetiva. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possível é sim, todas linguagens de programação podem fazer qualquer coisa. A questão é o trabalho que dá, geralmente é tanto, o risco é tão grande, que reescrever será ruim, escrever a mesma coisa do zero é muito mais interessante.

Se o código é em C# é improvável que use algum ponteiro. É muito raro ver o uso de ponteiro em C#, e agora quase todas situações não precisa mais, e onde precisa é em algo que não faz sentido portar para Node. Em C depende de muita coisa, mas não faz muito sentido fazer este tipo de conversão.

Mais ainda, se tem códigos bons rodando em C ou C++ ou C# não entendo porque querer convertê-lo para JavaScript principalmente para rodar no Node. O .NET tem a mesma capacidade e é absurdamente mais rápido que o Node/Deno. Se tem o código que resolve seu problema, use-o diretamente. Pra que trocar por uma linguagem menos robusta?

Se acha que pegará uma linguagem e transformará o código instrução por instrução para outra linguagem, nem comece, porque não é só que isto não ocorre, isso significa que tem uma ingenuidade que certamente resultará em o final ruim. Não tem mágica, não tem almoço grátis. Seja lá o que está pretendendo fazer não tem cara que vai dar certo. Uma pessoa experiente sabe que mesmo ela não teria bom resultado e provavelmente não o faria. Ela entenderia o problema e escreveria um código até melhor. Ou usaria a ferramenta certa. Se está querendo fazer isso deve dominar bem (de verdade) todas essas linguagens, é a única chance de dar certo, e aí começa fazer menos sentido converter, por isso ninguém o faz.

Todos os objetos em JS são tipos por referência. O ponteiro é o que faz algo ser acessado como uma referência, então qualquer coisa que encapsule em um objeto está usando um ponteiro. O fato de não saber disto, e nenhum problema as pessoas não saberem porque não precisam usar algo assim, mostra que não está preparado para fazer a conversão, esta é a parte fácil, encontrará muitas dificuldade no percurso que não saberá como lidar, por isso é um projeto fadado ao fracasso. Lamento, mas a solução não é essa.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Talvez você tenha me interpretado mal... Eu entendi perfeitamente o que quis dizer e concordo, não faz sentido reescrever algo que está pronto. A questão é a seguinte: eu tenho um projeto em C# e eu gostaria de tê-lo rodando em Node (por alguns motivos), esse projeto utiliza uma biblioteca escrita por uma pessoa que utiliza esse recurso, eu gostaria de entender porque e como ele usa e escrever em JavaScript algo que tivesse o mesmo resultado (ou até melhor), precisava saber se o fato se estar usando isso no C# não tornaria impossível reproduzir em Node.

Comment: Realmente não faz sentido, por isso eu falei para usar a linguagem que já tem o que você quer e não para reescrever, eu falei para desistir do Node e usar o que tem em C# pronto, em C# mesmo. Você que não entendeu isso. "eu tenho um projeto em C# e eu gostaria de tê-lo rodando em Node" isto é desejo, não necessidade, então largue essa ideia e seja feliz. Se a motivação fosse real teria até colocado na pergunta. No geral a resposta é que tudo dá para converter, mas que não deve. No específico também respondi. E te mostrei o caminho correto também, está tudo na resposta.

Comment: O que comentou é o oposto do que quer fazer: "eu gostaria de entender porque e como ele usa e escrever em JavaScript algo que tivesse o mesmo resultado (ou até melhor)". Ter o mesmo resultado não é portando o código é entendendo e fazendo outro código, portar não dá certo em quase todas situações, e quando dá é só que domina muito o que está fazendo. E não será melhor em hipótese alguma, será ruim, só deveria fazer isto em último caso, e admitindo que ficará ruim. Minha experiência é esta, mas é direito seu fazer do jeito errado, o alerta foi dado.

Comment: Como eu disse, eu entendi o seu ponto, mas ainda receio que tenha me expressado mal e você não tenha me compreendido. Estou aceitando a resposta. Mas quero acrescentar que eu consegui fazer o que eu necessitava, a aplicação ela é feita em C#. Eu quero reproduzi-la em NodeJS (e não é apenas uma questão de gosto, envolve até mesmo custos). Essa questão dos ponteiros é referente a uma classe específica que a aplicação usa, e eu precisava ter essa biblioteca reescrita em Node para completar a aplicação. Depois de algum tempo estudando, consegui reproduzir perfeitamente. Missão cumprida. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Vou te dar uma resposta muito superfla mas que é facil de entender, (desculpe o pessoal que gosta das coisas ao pé da letra)

O primeiro ponto é você entender o que os ponteiros fazem em linguagens como c
Os ponteiros são usados para fazer passagem por referencia e em linguagens orientadas a objeto geralmente todo objeto já é implícito que existe a passagem por referência

```js
    function funcao(obj){
       //Qualquer codigo que altere o obj aqui dentro reflete fora do escopo da função pois é implicito que o objeto tem uma passagem por referência
    }
```

ou seja vc usa ponteiros sem saber que está usando.

Comment: concordo. na verdade, para os que vierem a ter essa mesma dúvida, é só entender um pouco melhor como os ponteiros funcionam (a questão da referência, endereços da memória e etc.), eu estudei um pouco mais, fiz alguns códigos simples e repliquei-os com JavaScript. quando os resultados foram batendo, fui seguindo a lógica para escrever o que precisava.

Comment: Negativo, nem todo objeto já é implícito que existe passagem por referência. Além disso em linguagens como o PHP por exemplo você faz uso da instrução "&" antes da variável para explicitá-la como referência - por isso é muito comum memory leaks em linguagens como JavaScript / Node a pessoa não faz ideia que existe uma forma de passagem de um array para uma função que executa uma cópia invés da referência e por derivação isso se aplica a um Array de Objetos - de forma bastante simplista e grosseira é isso.